# Reorder object hierarchy and group by time in JSONata

Tags: jsonata

Although I'm not a total JSONata noob, I'm having a hard time finding an elegant solution to the following desired transformation. The starting point is a set of time-series data in a format like this:

```json
{
  "series1": {
    "data": [
         {"time": "2022-01-01T00:00:00Z", "value": 22},
         {"time": "2022-01-02T00:00:00Z", "value": 23}
    ]
  },
  "series2": {
    "data": [
         {"time": "2022-01-01T00:00:00Z","value": 220},
         {"time": "2022-01-02T00:00:00Z","value": 230}
    ]
  }
}
```

I need to "flip the hierarchy", and group these datapoints by timestamp, into an array of objects, like follows:

```json
[
  {
    "time": "2022-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "series1": 22,
    "series2": 220
  },
  {
    "time": "2022-01-02T00:00:00Z",
    "series1": 23,
    "series2": 230
  }
]
```

I currently have this working with the expression

```js
$each($, function($v, $s) {
  [$v.data.{
    'series': $s,
    'time':$.time,
    'value': $.value
  }]
}).*{
  `time`: {
    `series`: value
  }
}
~> $each(function($v, $t) {
  $merge([
    $v,
    {'time': $t}
  ])
})
```

(playground link: https://try.jsonata.org/8CaggujJk)

...and...I can't help but feel that there must be a better way!

For reference, my current expression basically does this in three consecutive steps:

1. The first `$each()` function, which splits up the original object into an array of datapoints, with a series name, timestamp, and value of each.
2. A grouping operator which makes `time` a key, and gathers all values for a given timestamp together.
3. A second `$each()` function, which transforms the object into an array of objects where `time` is a value again, rather than a key - and merges the `time` key-value alongside the series values.

I've seen some wonderfully elegant solutions to similar problems on here, but am not sure how to approach this in a better way. Any tips appreciated!